# SQL Merge table rows based on IN criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table result like following

```
Code    Counts1    Counts2   TotalCounts
1       10         20        30
4       15         18        33
5       5          14        19
...     ...        ...       ...
```

What I am trying to achieve is merging counts for all rows where Code (the column counts are grouped on) belongs IN (1,4). However, within all my research, all I found was methods to merge rows based on a common value for each row (same id, etc.)

Is there a way to merge rows based on IN criteria, so I know if I should research it further?

Comment: What is the Code for 1 and 4 after the merge?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Now that I think about it, it would be '1,4', but I have already researched that part. It won't be part of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a union?

```
select
   1 as Code,
   sum(Counts1) as Counts1,
   sum(Counts2) as Counts2,
   sum(TotalCount) as TotalCounts
from
   YourTable
where
   code in (1,4)

union
select * 
from 
   YourTable
where 
   code not in(1,4)
```

Comment: Makes sense.. I will try our suggestion right away, and will reply as soon as I get close to it. My real result set is just a liiiiittle bit more complex than that...

Comment: I see what you are saying @JohnCappelletti i'll add an edit. I read the question slightly different at first.

Comment: Your Union suggestion generated several ideas in my mind, so thank you, I accepted your answer as a primary.

Comment: Glad to help @VadzimSavenok

Answer (score 2):

Just assuming you will have numerous groupings (See the @Groupings mapping table)

You can have dynamic groupings via a `LEFT JOIN`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Code] varchar(50),[Counts1] int,[Counts2] int,[TotalCounts] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,10,20,30)
,(4,15,18,33)
,(5,5,14,19)

Declare @Groupings Table (Code varchar(50),Grp int)
Insert Into @Groupings values
 (1,1)
,(4,1)


select code    = Isnull(B.NewCode,A.Code)
      ,Counts1 = sum(Counts1)
      ,Counts2 = sum(Counts2) 
      ,TotalCounts = sum(TotalCounts)
 From  @YourTable A
 Left Join (
        Select *
              ,NewCode = (Select Stuff((Select ',' + Code From @Groupings Where Grp=B1.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
         From  @Groupings  B1
       ) B on (A.Code=B.Code)
 Group By Isnull(B.NewCode,A.Code)
```

**Returns**

```
code    Counts1 Counts2 TotalCounts
1,4     25      38      63
5       5       14      19
```

**If it helps with the Visualization, the subquery generates**

```
Code    Grp NewCode
1       1   1,4
4       1   1,4
```

Comment: +1 for dynamic grouping, but I will take scsimon's answer as more elegant solution fitting my need. He also pointed me into Union territory, which generated several ideas in my mind. But you deserve a credit for your effort, thank you.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok That's the great thing about SO.  You get options and pick the one that works best for you.

Comment: Absolutely agree, but even better, that others can be credited for their efforts as well, not just a single individual.

Answer (score 1):

sum the count, remove code from the select statement. Add a new column to group 1 and 4 using case statement lets name this groupN. then in SQL group it by groupN.

You are correct, grouping has to be based on common value. so by creating a new column, you are making that happen.